# Cannot shift right-click in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing with version 1.7.10 on PC and I seem to be unable to use the Shift and right-click, for instance to put two droppers on top of each other facing up or down. I have already read several posts with similar problems and all of them suggested these fixes:

- turn screen mode on/off
- try with both left and right shift
- click F11 twice
- try shift ENTER instead
- try with right shift and control
- try with left shift and control
- press the "pick block" key and try again
- restart game
- download minecraft again and re-install
- update LWJGL

I have tried all except the last one - I don't see how a "game developing API" should have anything to do with it, the game should run fine with the newest version of JRE. Although I can put two droppers next to each other using a temporary block, this only works if the droppers are not facing up or down. Are there any other solutions I haven't mentioned already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your LWJGL. LWJGL is what actually handles the graphics and input, and interprets it in a way Java can understand. If your input doesn't work correctly, chances are it's LWJGL not working correctly.

If that doesn't work, rebind your sneak key to something else, and hold that instead of Shift.

Comment: Excellent you were right about the sneak key - I simply use that along with right-clicking and now everything works!